# Fixing layout in Word document so users entering text doesn't alter spacing

Tags: microsoft-word, layout

I have a Word document for users to fill in with a number of headings. I would like them to fill in text in the blank spaces, but without the page shifting down as they type (so in essence they would have a fixed space to enter their answers).

Is there any way to do this? The only way I'm aware of which is using the "Text box" shape, which isn't ideal.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure why the text box is a bad idea, you can hide the border so it merges with the word document and will not affect the layout of the document.

Answer (score 0):

You could use tables (with visible or invisible borders, your choice) and set the row height to an "exact" height rather than "at least" or auto.